# Prove that $83$ divides $p$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

> Let $p$ and $q$ be the positive integers such that $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - ... - \frac{1}{54} + \frac{1}{55} = \frac{p}{q}$ . Prove that $83$ divides $p$ .

**What I Tried** :- To me it does not actually seem like an easy problem for me. (I guess I couldn't figure out the idea)

This expression I found is same as $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{55} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$
And calculating this in Wolfram Alpha gives the answer to be this in the simplest form :- $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{55} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\frac{115328583812490186710549}{164249358725037825439200}$$

Surprisingly, I found that $83$ really divides the numerator of the fraction. Now I got puzzled, how will you show this without using Wolfram Alpha or a Calculator?

Can Anyone Help?

Comment: Hint : The question isn't asking for a numerical value. So to show $83$ divides $p$, some clever rearrangement is enough.

Comment: @cosmo5 I know there is some such arrangement , I just got this result by using my resources. The question is :- What?

Comment: See [$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\dots+\frac{1}{1331}=\frac{p}{q}$; is $p$ divisible by $1997$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993852/1-frac12-frac13-frac14-frac15-dots-frac11331-fracp) and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1683655p10740125

Comment: Oh It does , I guess it should be a duplicate then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given expression is

$$
1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - ... - \frac{1}{54} + \frac{1}{55} \\ 
= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ...  + \frac{1}{55} - 2(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + ...  + \frac{1}{54} ) \\ 
= \frac{1}{28} + \frac{1}{29}  ...  + \frac{1}{55} \\
 = (\frac{1}{28} + \frac{1}{55}) + (\frac{1}{29} + \frac{1}{54}) + \ldots \\ 
= 83 (\frac{1}{28\cdot55} + \frac{1}{29\cdot54} + \ldots) = \frac{p}{q}
$$

from which it follows.

Comment: @Anonymous, thank you! Alternative signs should now hint you to above technique.